# Some applications will launch very slowly after closing a game (Windows 10)

Tags: windows, windows-10, performance, gaming

I have a very weird problem. When I close games, some applications will take noticeably long to launch.

For example, if I close the game (MOHAA) and then start VLC application, it will be extremely slow to launch. It will take like 15 seconds for example. I looked under Process manager and I don't see VLC's process there only after the long wait it shows up. Once VLC starts up, closing it and reopen it will be quick. Now weirdly this only happens if I don't run the game as Admin. Running the game as Admin and closing it doesn't cause this issue.

What could really be the issue here?
I have the latest Windows 10 with all updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems my issue was AMD Adrenalin software. After uninstalling and installing the AMD Adrenalin software, my issue is now resolved.